# foreach only once

Tags: wordpress, foreach

I'm using metabox plugin for wordpress, there are one php command:

```
<?php

$images = rwmb_meta( 'pw_project_photos', array('type'=>'plupload_image','size'=>'thumbnail') );
foreach ( $images as $image )
{
    echo "<img src='{$image['url']}' alt='{$image['alt']}' />";
}

?>
```

what I want to to do is only echo once, is it possbile?

for example, I have upload two images to one post, but I only want to show the first image, not two images.

plz help me, thx a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really don't need to loop through the array if you only want to echo one item.

Simply do:

```
<?php
if ( isset( $images[0] ) ) {
   $image = $images[0];
   echo "<img src='{$image['url']}' alt='{$image['alt']}' />";
} 
?>
```

Comment: Hi, kjetilh,I use the code below, but can not worked, it can not echo the image, it's become empty output, plz advise, much thx! <?php     
      $images = rwmb_meta( 'pw_project_photos', array('type'=>'plupload_image','size'=>'thumbnail') );
      if ( isset( $images[0] ) ) {
   $image = $images[0];
   echo "<img src='{$image['url']}' alt='{$image['alt']}' />";
} 
      ;?>

Comment: Please run `var_dump($images);` after you've retrieved the images to see if it contains anything.